# Redirection does not switch from POST to GET with go on appengine standard

Tags: google-app-engine, go, redirect

Like the title says, a curl request to the following server written for appengine with GO doesn't switch from POST to GET despite the redirection :

```
func init() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        switch r.Method {
        case "GET":
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "INDEX")
        case "POST":
            fmt.Print("redirecting...")
            http.Redirect(w, r, "/", http.StatusTemporaryRedirect)
        default:
            http.NotFound(w, r)
        }
    })
}
```

Instead, I get an infinite redirection loop, no matter what status code I try (302,303,...)

My routing in app.yaml for the record :

```
- url: /.*
  script: _go_app
```

And the curl command used locally :

```
curl "http://localhost:8080" -X POST -L
```

How do I fix this ? thanks .

EDIT:
The behavior remained unchanged with 302

```
http.Redirect(w, r, "/", http.StatusFound)
```

It is still stuck in a redirection loop

Comment: `http.StatusTemporaryRedirect` isn't supposed to switch methods. Does it work with `http.StatusFound`?

Comment: @JimB as said in my question it does NOT work with http.StatusFound either .

Comment: OK, not a `curl` bug, we didn't read the man page section for `-X`: `The method string you set with -X will be used for all requests, which if you for example use -L, --location may cause unintended side-effects when curl doesn't change request method according to the HTTP 30x response codes - and similar.`

Comment: looks like you're totally right, please write an answer so I can accept it as the answer to my issue. curl behavior however is definitely not very intuitive. for post requests, no need for the -X flag. a simple -d flag marks the request as post !?